# Using a WebGrid in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC3 and trying desperately to just get something simple working. I feel like I'm trying to do something very simple. However, I can't get a basic grid to work. I'm using the default setup in Visual Studio, and here is what I've done:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        List<Person> test = new List<Person>();
        test.Add(new Person("John", "Smith"));
        test.Add(new Person("Bill", "Torr"));

        return View(test);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(@Model);
    grid.GetHtml();    
}
</p>
```

Oddly, nothing is printed out for the WebGrid. I was expecting two rows. Instead, I got nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to strongly type your view and to output the result of the `GetHtml` method to the view output stream. Here you go:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<p>@grid.GetHtml()</p>
```

Notice how the `@grid.GetHtml()` is externalized from the code section which is what basically writes the grid HTML to the output stream. In your example you was calling `grid.GetHtml()` inside the code section but you was not doing anything with the results like for example outputting them. That's the reason they were going into oblivion.

Comment: But I can't reference Person in the .cshtml file. If I try @model IEnumerable<object> nothing shows up either.

Comment: @Villager, of course that you can reference it. Simply provide it's full namespace `@model IEnumerable<YourAppName.Models.Person>`. Or even better, add this namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file so that you don't have to do it all over again in all your views.

Comment: @Villager, great, is there something else you are willing to ask or can we consider this thread as closed in which case you shouldn't hesitate to mark the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this also this show how to use webgrid and ajax in mvc3
http://www.helpnshareidea.in/2014/01/webgrid-in-mvc3-using-ajax.html